# Segfault when I'm adding object to <vector>

Tags: c++, boost, vector, ublas

I wrote pieces of code two different ways: using 2-dimensional array as matrix, and using boost::ublas::matrix. When I'm adding this object to  in the first case it is working, but in the second I'm getting a segmentation fault. I want to use the second way, so if anybody knows why am I getting the segfault I'll be grateful.

The code:

## img.h

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

class Img
{
    public:
        Img();
        Img(const string path2file);

        unsigned int width, height;
        string filename;
    private:
        typedef struct pix
        {
            Quantum R;
            Quantum G;
            Quantum B;
        } pix;

        matrix<pix> p;

        pix **pixels;
    string format;
};
```

## img.cpp

```
Img::Img(const string path2file)
{
 Image file;
 unsigned int i, j;
 Color pixel;

 file.read(path2file);

 filename = path2file;
 width = file.size().width();
 height = file.size().height();

// begin of first way
 pixels = (pix**)malloc(sizeof(pix*)*height);
 for(i=0 ; i<height ; ++i)
  pixels[i] = (pix*)malloc(sizeof(pix)*width);

 for(i=0 ; i<height ; ++i)
 {
  for(j=0 ; j<width ; ++j)
  {
   pixel = file.pixelColor(j, i);

   pixels[i][j].R = pixel.redQuantum();
   pixels[i][j].G = pixel.greenQuantum();
   pixels[i][j].B = pixel.blueQuantum();
  }
 }
// end of first way

// begin of second way
 p.resize(height, width);
 for(i=0 ; i<height ; ++i)
 {
  for(j=0 ; j<width ; ++j)
  {
   pixel = file.pixelColor(j, i);

   p(i, j).R = pixel.redQuantum();
   p(i, j).G = pixel.greenQuantum();
   p(i, j).B = pixel.blueQuantum();
  }
 }*/
}
// end of second way
```

I'm pretty sure that this code isn't the cause of the segfaults.
But when I use it in the main program I'm getting segfaults (only for second way, first is working):

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "img.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
 std::vector<Img> files;
 files.push_back(Img("files/mini.bmp"));
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger? Or Valgrind?

Comment: Is the vector actually relevant at all? Try constructing the `Img` object by itself instead of adding it to the vector directly. That will help you determine whether adding the object to the vector is really the problem, as you said it is.

Comment: @chrisaycock, you mean C++ proram :)

Comment: @Rob is right. Make sure you can build a uBlas `matrix` the way to you are building it first. Then you can worry about whether you are copying it correctly second. (By the way, the pointer version is probably more efficient since it's not copying a whole matrix; make sure your destructor frees the memory though. And don't use `malloc()` in a C++ program!)

Comment: @David Blech, just realized that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Load the program into gdb and make it crash. Type into the gdb console bt or backtrace and you will get a stack frame of all the calls made and you can see what is causing the segfault.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the first thing one shall try; using `frame` command on a given frame to access a given frame's locals is often useful in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in definition of  as I wrote.
should be:

```
vector<Img*> files;
```

instead of

```
vector<Img> files;
```

and change initializing objects from

```
Img tmp("path_to_file");
```

to

```
Img* tmp = new Img("path_to_file");
```

I'm very tired of coding all day, so I make ridiculous mistakes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Run your program under [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org), it will help you find the cause and location of the segfault.

Answer (score 0):

```
pixels = (pix**)malloc(sizeof(pix*)*height);
```

This seems weird, malloc returns a (void) pointer, not a pointer to a pointer but it could work for a [][] array I guess. After re-proofreading it seems its OK :p

Having both a class Img and then another Image that you instantiate with a variable named 'file' might be a bit confusing.

Some code is also missing (what is 'p' for example) but what's there seems OK. If I was you I'd put some printf() here and there to narrow where the program crashes.
My best bet would be that the p(i,j) indexation might be out of bound.

Good luck!